# Minimum records in Excel for converting to shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, features

I'm converting an Excel spreadsheet with 3000 rows and 10 columns. My problem is while exporting Excel to a shapefile I get an error that states:

`The Maximum Record length has been exceeded.`

Comment: Although a bit tideous, you can try to split your excel sheet in several parts (at least to find where the limit is) and import them one at the time. After that Merge (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) can be used to add them all together again.

Comment: Does some of your cells contain a large amount of text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt it has to do with the number of entries. I just added XY data for an Excel spreadsheet of 50000 rows by 17 columns of text of 200 characters and it exported to shapefile without a hiccup.

From the error message page:

> ### **001337 : The maximum record length has been exceeded.**
>
> The record length is the number of bytes used to define all the fields
>   in a table, not the number of bytes used to store the actual values.

So you might either have field names that are very long or plenty of blank rows to the right that might be getting picked up and adding to the running total (4,000 bytes is the max).

[This](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005600000013000000) outlines some limitations on shapefile attributes.

Comment: (+1) Although you accurately quote the ESRI help page concerning the (alleged) 4K byte limitation, that is not part of the dBase standard, which allows up to 256 fields of up to 254 characters each (almost 32K bytes total). Moreover, older ESRI software did not suffer from this 4K limitation, so for others in a similar situation it might be worth testing to see whether the documentation is correct.